# ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub") => NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, dependency-management

I program a console application for my app with language C# with framework dotnetcoreapp2.0 necessary to run lower specs computers. I know the warning but its necessary for windows functionality and demands. I already Add Project Reference on Visual Basic from `C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and added with

`v4.0.30319`. I installed dotnetcoreapp2.0 runtime and its sdk. The problem is, whenever I called the static class with the Management.. programming, error occurs with System.NullReferenceException after W/o Debug. Ill provide the programming.

```
>1.using System; 
>2.using System.Collections.Generic; 
>3.using System.Text;
>4.using System.Management; 
>5.using System.IO; 
>6.using System.Windows; 
>7.using System.Linq; 
>8.using System.Collections; 
>9.using System.Data; 
>10.using System.ComponentModel; 
>11.using System.Windows.Forms;
>12. 
>13.namespace USBConsoleMonitor 
>14.{  
>15.class All_Driver_Existence 
>16.{  
>17.public static void Device_ALL() 
>18.{ 
>19.try 
>20.{ 
>21.ObjectQuery yep = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub"); 
>22.ManagementScope yen = new ManagementScope("\\root\\cimv2");//default 
>23.ManagementObjectSearcher yes = new ManagementObjectSearcher(yen, yep);
>24.
>25.foreach (ManagementObject yesnt in yes.Get()) 
>26.{ 
>27.Console.WriteLine(yesnt["Name"]); 
>28.} 
>29.catch (ObjectNotFoundException) 
>30.{ 
>31.Console. WriteLine("Does not found on context ... "); 
>32.} 
>33.catch (NullReferenceException) 
>34.{ 
>35.Console.WriteLine("Somethings wrong with \\root\\cimv2"); 
>36.} } } } 
>37.static void Main(string[] args) 
>38.{ 
>39. . . .
>40.All_Driver_Existence.DeviceALL(); 
>41. . . . 
>42.} 
>43.}
```

Error Code Line 22 and Line 40
Stack trace:

Visual Studio (Without  debug)

```
>Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>at System.Management.MTAHelper.IsNoContextMTA()
>at System.Management.MTAHelper.CreateInMTA(Type type)
>at System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(String path)
>at USBConsoleMonitor.All_Driver_Existence.Device_ALL() in >C:\Users\ComputerName\OneDrive\Desktop\Console Leader\USBConsoleMonitor\DeviceDriver.cs:line 25
>at USBConsoleMonitor.Runner.Main(String[] args) in >C:\Users\ComputerName\OneDrive\Desktop\Console Leader\USBConsoleMonitor\Runner.cs:line 27
```

Powershell

```
PS C:\Users\stran> System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub")
System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher : The term 'System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Manageme...tObjectSearcher:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Does it have to do with AMD GPU? I use a laptop to program anyways. Also, I am a hardware, software developer. I am keen to learn more about C# and all of Visual Studio.

Comment: I also use WMICODECREATOR -> found on Microsoft Downloads for automatic programming solution. The code does not work.

Comment: The dependencies does not have a yellow status or for removal on error list

Comment: I seek solution with the Windows Powershell, it displays the same as my program tries to access. Same value. Through this syntax:: System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub")

Comment: Hi, Can you please format the code properly & add the exact error message & stack trace.

Comment: I finish revise the body today for specifications. Alex K